# Dependence of EMF of a cell on stoichiometry

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, reduction-potential

In the reaction $\ce{Zn + 2Ag+ -> Zn^2+ + 2Ag}$ , my book says that the EMF is the difference between the standard reduction potential of $\ce{Ag}$ and $\ce{Zn}$.

Shouldn't it be the difference between **twice** the potential of $\ce{Ag}$ and $\ce{Zn}$ since two moles of $\ce{Ag}$ are getting reduced per mole of $\ce{Zn?}$

Answer (score 1):

The electromotive force of a redox reaction is not dependent on the coefficients in the balanced equation as it is an intensive property (i.e. a property that does not depend on the size of the system). Thus, your reasoning is incorrect.

You can read more about electrochemistry here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Analytical_Chemistry/Electrochemistry/Basics_of_Electrochemistry

Also, I am wondering if your textbook is actually correct because $\ce{Ag2+ + e- -> 2Ag}$ and $\ce{Ag+ + e- -> Ag}$ are definitely different. Thus, the standard reduction potential of silver (I) should not be used. Instead, the standard reduction potential of $\ce{Ag2+}$ should be used. Someone who is more knowledgeable in this area please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The standard cell potential is an intensive property and therefore doesn't depend upon the stoichiometry rather you can use the relation ∆G=-nFE(standard potential) to prove the result for the standard cell potential because ∆G is an extensive property.